# I'm having a TypeError with my Python code

Tags: typeerror

I have an assignment where I have to calculate grades for both quizzes and exams and then calculate the total average between the two. As you could see I'm clearly not done with it.

```
quizW = .30
examW = .70

quizSum = 0

numQuiz = int(input("How many quizzes: ")) 
quizGrade = {}

for x in range(numQuiz):
    quizGrade[x] = (input("What is the grade for quiz " + str(x) + ": "))
    quizSum = quizSum + quizGrade
    
print(quizSum)
```

It was working at first, until I added `quizSum = quizSum + quizGrade` to the for loop.

After adding that, I keep getting this error:

```
line 10, in <module>
    quizGrade[x] = (input("What is the grade for quiz " + str(x) + ": "))
TypeError: 'int' object does not support item assignment
```

Is there any way to fix this? if so, that would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the issue here is that you try to add a *list* to an *int*. Because of that, you get your error. Try adding an element of the list instead.

Change the 10th line to

```
quizSum = quizSum + quizGrade[x]
```

But, to be honest, you don't need to use the list in the first place.

The following will work fine as well:

```
quizW = .30
examW = .70

quizSum = 0

numQuiz = int(input("How many quizzes: ")) 

for x in range(numQuiz):
    quizGrade = (input("What is the grade for quiz " + str(x) + ": "))
    quizSum = quizSum + quizGrade
```